# How can I force the UIInterpolatingMotionEffect to refresh the views without the device being moved?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, motion

I use a vertical and horizontal UIInterpolatingMotionEffect for each view in my app.

```
_horizontalEffect = [[UIInterpolatingMotionEffect alloc] initWithKeyPath:@"center.x" type:UIInterpolatingMotionEffectTypeTiltAlongHorizontalAxis];
_verticalEffect = [[UIInterpolatingMotionEffect alloc] initWithKeyPath:@"center.y" type:UIInterpolatingMotionEffectTypeTiltAlongVerticalAxis];
```

The .minimum and .maximum relative values are relative to the view's size **and change each time the size of the view changes**.

```
_horizontalEffect.minimumRelativeValue = @(size.width / 10.0);
_horizontalEffect.maximumRelativeValue = @(-size.height / 10.0);
_verticalEffect.minimumRelativeValue = @(size.width / 10.0);
_verticalEffect.maximumRelativeValue = @(-size.height / 10.0);
```

**The user can change the size of the view by using a UISlider**. Also, he can do a lot of view.center changes on all the views without the device being moved.

The problem is that if the device doesn’t move the views are not updated according to UIInterpolatingMotionEffect and they look misaligned.

How can I force the UIInterpolatingMotionEffect to refresh the views without the device being moved?

Maybe, I'm asking the wrong question but I really need some guidance here.